# Python Twitch API Attribute Error problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests, twitch

I received the error: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items' while trying to get info via twitch API.

```
import requests

ENDPOINT = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/clips/top?channel=Twitch&period=month&trending=true&limit=1'

HEAD = {
    'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json',
    'Client-ID: HIDDEN',
}

response = requests.get(url=ENDPOINT, headers=HEAD)
print (response.text)
```

Comment: my bad, marked as the right answer. Thanks for the help Amir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the way you have defined your header in HEAD, you have actually created a `set`, not a `dictionary`. Revise your HEAD as follows:

```
HEAD = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json',
    'Client-ID': 'HIDDEN',
}
```

Not that the `key` and `value` are wrapped inside a quotation.

**`Dictionary`:**

```
{'key', 'value'}
```

**What you had done was to create a `Set`:**

```
{'key value'}
```